# c++ embeded template templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, angelscript

I have a class that 'wraps' an AngelScript Method.  Basically, you send it the Class, method return type, a pointer to the method, and a list of arguments.

So far, I am able to successfully make this `Method` object when I am 'binding' a class method that takes no parameters.  However, if I try to add parameters, it breaks.

I am doing something like this:

```
template<typename C, typename R, R (C::*fn)(), typename... Arguments>
class Method {
public:
    Method()
    {
        const asSFuncPtr& func = asSMethodPtr<sizeof( void (C::*)() )>::Convert( AS_METHOD_AMBIGUITY_CAST( R (C::*)(Arguments... parameters)) (fn) );
        function = &func;
    };
    virtual ~Method(){};
    const asSFuncPtr* function;
};

struct S
{
    int f()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    int f(int a)
    {
        return a + 1;
    }
};
```

And then creating my `Method` object like so:

```
Method<S, int, &S::f> m = Method<S, int, &S::f>();
```

This works.

However, if I try to make a method object like this:

```
Method<S, int, &S::f, int> m2 = Method<S, int, &S::f, int>();
```

It breaks with this message:

```
template_tests.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Method<C, R, fn, Arguments>::Method() [with C = S; R = int; R (C::* fn)() = &S::f; Arguments = {int}]’:
template_tests.cpp:74:61:   required from here
template_tests.cpp:27:142: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘int (S::*)()’ to type ‘int (S::*)(int)’
```

Which makes sense, since I'm passing a pointer to a function that has no parameters.

Now, how do I change the `Method` class to accept method pointers to class methods that have varying number of parameters?

Do I do something like this:

```
template<typename C, typename R, R (C::*fn)(Arguments... parameters), typename... Arguments>
class Method {
...
}
```

Because doing that causes all sorts of errors..

Basically, I guess I'm asking - how do I 'embed' variadic templates inside a template template?  Is this possible?

Comment: Do you really need the arguments and return types separately?  What if `Method` was something like `template <typename C,typename Func,Func C::*fn> class Method`, and used like `Method<S,int(int),&S::f>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the surface, it seems like your `Method` class doesn't really need the return type and the argument types, it just needs the the whole function type.  In that case, `Method` could be defined like this:

```
template <typename C,typename Func,Func C::*fn>
struct Method {
public:
    Method()
    {
        const asSFuncPtr& func = 
           asSMethodPtr<sizeof( void (C::*)() )>::Convert( 
               AS_METHOD_AMBIGUITY_CAST(Func C::*) (fn) 
           );
        function = &func;
    };
    virtual ~Method(){};
    const asSFuncPtr* function;
};
```

and then used like this if the method takes no parameters:

```
Method<S, int(), &S::f> m;
```

or this if the method takes an int parameter:

```
Method<S, int(int), &S::f> m;
```

Comment: Yes, and then some variadic template helper classes could be used to pull apart the return type and argument types

Comment: wow - that worked perfectly.  Thanks so much @Vaughn!  I definitely have a lot to learn with this c++ template stuff.